# how to I enable remote desktop on specific domain machine only

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, domain-controller

I have created an Organization and assigned a GPO to it. I have 3 computers on this domain. The domain controller, the remote desktop computer, and the sql server.

I only want to enable remote desktop for this organization only on the remote desktop computer but disabling it for the others. Is this possible?  If so, can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered just doing it? Enabling remote desktop on a server is a willfull act (switch in server manager) or a policy - default is off. So, you DID enable it as you wanted.

Also per default on servers you must be admin to log in. As such, this is a moot limitation - normal users have no access unless you manage to rip out and totally shred the security that is there from the start.

Comment: ah ok... I reread your last sentence. The CALS are only on the rdp machine so in such, since they are not administrators, they cannot log into the other two anyhow, correct?

Comment: No. There is another policy saying ONLY ADMINS ARE ALLOWED. That is separate from enabling RDP for remote administration. Normal users have no right to log onto a server with an interactive session (i.e. a desktop). Not physically, not remotely. Same permission - they also can not log onto the machine when they have physical access. The standard admin access is admin only.

Comment: That is, unless you actually - install the terminal server role, then this is a termina lserver (lots more setup including a licensing system) for end users. But standard RDP access is admin only access.